# Page layout changes after opening registration modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

This is a weird error that I'm experiencing and I've no idea why. When I first open the website the pages look normal like this
[image]

But after I open the registration modal (the link to it is inside the login modal) the layout changes to the following

[image]

Notice the weird gap on the right of the screen. This is my code on GitHub https://github.com/Arefaat18/Project  I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.